# SQL Server 2008 Stored Procedure returns only first column in expected results

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have the following stored procedure that I need to return multiple types of data for an annual report.  For some reason I only get the first column in the results.  If I comment out the NumOfBonds column, the TotalAmount column is the only one returned.  I need it to return all these rows, but for some reason I am only getting one when I execute the procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.AnnualReport
    @Agency varchar(50),
    @Subagency varchar(50),
    @StartDate datetime,
    @EndDate datetime
AS
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS NumOfBonds, SUM(ISNULL(Powers.BondAmount, 0)) + SUM(ISNULL(Charges.BondAmount, 0)) AS TotalAmount,
    SUM(ISNULL(Powers.BondPremium, 0)) + SUM(ISNULL(Charges.BondPremium, 0)) AS TotalPremium,
    SUM(ISNULL(Powers.BondPremium, 0)) + SUM(ISNULL(Charges.BondPremium, 0)) + SUM(ISNULL(Fees.Amount, 0))
    + SUM(ISNULL(ForfeitureExpense.Amount, 0)) - SUM(ISNULL(Payment.Amount, 0)) AS TotalBalance
    FROM Bond
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
    (
        SELECT Powers.Bond, SUM(Charge.BondAmount) AS BondAmount, SUM(Charge.BondPremium) AS BondPremium
        FROM Powers INNER JOIN Charge ON Powers.Surety = Charge.PowerSurety
        AND Powers.PowerPrefix = Charge.PowerPrefix AND Powers.PowerNumber = Charge.PowerNumber
        GROUP BY Powers.Bond
    ) AS Powers ON Bond.ID = Powers.Bond
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
    (
        SELECT BondID, SUM(BondAmount) AS BondAmount, SUM(BondPremium) AS BondPremium
        FROM ChargeWithoutPower
        GROUP BY BondID
    ) AS Charges ON Bond.ID = Charges.BondID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
    (
        SELECT Bond, SUM(Amount) AS Amount
        FROM BondFee
        WHERE Date >= @StartDate AND Date <= @EndDate
        GROUP BY Bond
    ) AS Fees ON Bond.ID = Fees.Bond
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
    (
        SELECT Bond, SUM(Amount) AS Amount
        FROM ForfeitureExpense
        WHERE ExpenseDate >= @StartDate AND ExpenseDate <= @EndDate
        GROUP BY Bond
    ) AS ForfeitureExpense ON Bond.ID = ForfeitureExpense.Bond
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
    (
        SELECT Bond, SUM(Amount) AS Amount
        FROM Payment
        WHERE Date >= @StartDate AND Date <= @EndDate
        GROUP BY Bond
    ) AS Payment ON Bond.ID = Payment.Bond
    WHERE Bond.ReleaseDate >= @StartDate AND Bond.ReleaseDate <= @EndDate
    AND Bond.Agency = @Agency AND Bond.Subagency = @Subagency
    RETURN
```

The basic purpose is to give me the number of bonds written in that year, the total amount of the bonds in that year, the total premium on those bonds, and the balance at the end of the year for those bonds.  I am not sure why it only sees the first column and not the rest of them.

Comment: Do you get all the columns back if you try just running the SQL on its own, rather than via the stored proc?

Comment: No, I get all 4 columns when I just enter the query with explicit dates, agency, and subagency

Comment: It's hard to see an obvious problem However, I'm wondering if it's connected to the aliases you are using - for instance, in your first inline table, your are selecting from a table called Powers, but you have aliased the inline table as Powers as well, In your main select, your are referring to columns from Powers - how does SQL Server know whether you are referring to the inline table or the original table?

Comment: It knows because those are subqueries, so it doesn't see the tables from the joins, just the results from those queries labeled as the aliases.  I've used this exact styling on many other Stored Procedures.

I am implementing it in my C# code now to see if it gets the expected results that way.  It is just odd because all my other stored procedures will give me the expected results when I just execute them directly from the database, but that one will not.  As soon as I added it to my DataSet, it showed that 4 columns are returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, so the basic solution here is that executing the SQL Server 2008 Stored Procedure alone did not give the proper results in Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate, but as soon as I added it to my data set and executed the procedure from C# code, it solved the problem.  I'm not sure why this is, but I blame Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate.